# getElementById is returning null

Tags: javascript, csv

I'm attempting to read in a file using this form in my :

```
<form name="UploadForm" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
    Choose a CSV file to upload: <input name="upload_file" type="file" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" onClick="uploadFile()" />
</form>
```

But when I go to read the value in this function within  I receive a "cannon find "elements" of null error:

```
function uploadFile() {
        var file = document.getElementById('UploadForm').elements['upload_file'].value;
        var allTextLines = file.split(/\r\n|\n/);
        var headers = allTextLines[0].split(',');
        var lines = [];

        for (var i=1; i<allTextLines.length; i++) {
            var data = allTextLines[i].split(',');
            if (data.length == headers.length) {

                var tarr = [];
                for (var j=0; j<headers.length; j++) {
                    tarr.push(headers[j]+":"+data[j]);
                }
                lines.push(tarr);
            }
        }
        alert(lines);
    };
```

Does anybody have any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getElementById` returns the element with the specified id, but the form doesn't have an `id` at all. You are using the obsolete `name` attribute (which was superseded by `id` when HTML 4 was released in 1998).

Change it to:

```
<form id="UploadForm" method="post">
```

(N.B. `name` is *not* obsolete on form *controls*, such as `input` and `select`)

---

Note that your event handler isn't cancelling the default behaviour of the submit button. So as well as running the JS, you will immediately submit the form, leave the page, and cancel the JS (if it does anything asynchronous, which the name suggests it will be).

If you are going to use intrinsic event attributes, then you need to `return false` if the JavaScript succeeds.

I recommend giving them up in favour of [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener) though.

Answer (score 0):

Change your input tag to be like this:

```
 <input name="upload_file" id="upload_file" type="file" />
```

Also change this line from:
 document.getElementById('UploadForm').elements['upload_file'].value 

to
document.getElementById('upload_file').value